# Javascript external file not linking correctly

Tags: javascript, html

This is my first javascript that I have ever wrote aside from a few alerts and also my first post. So I have created an Html page and a external javascript file. Both files are in the same directory and I have checked the spellings of each file.

Here is the html code:

```
<body>

  <p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

   <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

     <button id="button1" onclick="divGrow">Grow</button>
     <button id="button2" onclick="divColor">Blue</button>
     <button id="button3" onclick="divFade">Fade</button>
     <button id="button4" onclick="divReset">Reset</button>

     <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript.js"></script>

  </body>
```

and here is the javascript file:

```
function divGrow() {

   alert("This grows the box");
   document.getElementById("box").style.width = "300px";
   document.getElementById("box").style.height = "300px";

 }

 function divColor() {

   alert("This changes the Box to Blue");
   document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "Blue";

  }

  function divFade() {

   alert("This fades the box");
   document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = ".5";

  }

 function divReset() {

  alert("This resets the box")
  document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "Orange"
  document.getElementById("box").style.width = "150px";
  document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px";
  document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "0";

 }
```

Am I missing another link? To make the javascript code work?

Comment: Have you [checked your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log) for errors?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot the `()` at the end of the function names.

```
 <button id="button1" onclick="divGrow()">Grow</button>
 <button id="button2" onclick="divColor()">Blue</button>
 <button id="button3" onclick="divFade()">Fade</button>
 <button id="button4" onclick="divReset()">Reset</button>
```